# Can I get checkboxes by ID and toggle classes without having repetitive classes & functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, toggle

I am toggling classes on a table to hide specific columns, based on checkboxes that are selected by the user above the table. The checkboxes have IDs "product_1", "product_2" etc.

There are 4 columns in the table, so I made 4 functions that do the toggling:

```
  const toggleFirst = document.getElementById('product_1').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#compare-table').classList.toggle('tb-compare-hide-1');
  });
  const toggleSecond = document.getElementById('product_2').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#compare-table').classList.toggle('tb-compare-hide-2');
  });
  const toggleThird = document.getElementById('product_3').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#compare-table').classList.toggle('tb-compare-hide-3');
  });
  const toggleFourth = document.getElementById('product_4').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#compare-table').classList.toggle('tb-compare-hide-4');
  });
```

The classes that are toggled then control the showing/hiding.

I have this working, but I have 4 CSS classes, and 4 JS functions, that are basically doing the same thing but with a different checkbox relating to a different class.

Can I achieve this with fewer repetitive classes and functions?

Comment: Are the checkboxes wrapped in another element? What is the basic HTML?

Comment: Wrap the checkboxes in a parent container. Put the listener on the parent then use _event delegation_ to query what's been clicked. You only need one listener then. For more info see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/event-delegation-in-javascript/)

Comment: I would use a data-attribute on each button to determine which class "iterator" to toggle, rather than hardcoding 1-4.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's opinion based

Comment: What's your HTML? We need enough code to reproduce your problem, and your problem is not purely the repetitive JavaScript. Please see the "*[mcve]*" guidance.

Comment: I believe I've included enough code and context for the problem at hand. The full HTML is not required because the context can be understood from the JS and the written description. See the other answers, they provide elegant solutions.

Comment: Also, I'm unsure why this should be closed as it's opinion based. That would apply to nearly all questions on this forum. There are objectively more elegant solutions available as per the answers I've recieved here!

Comment: "*I believe I've included enough code and context*" - and yet the expectations, and requirements, of the site disagree with your self-assessment. The purpose of the site isn't too help you, specifically, it's to provide useful answers that can help you and future visitors, who are quite likely to have different HTML, to learn how to use and apply code to their situation. With code that reproduces your problem we can demonstrate to you, and others, how a solution might be implemented.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation of the site rules. I gave enough context in the code, plus my write up. I kept it extremely clear. This provides the context that shows anyone else seeing this question what it's about. It can be applied to any class toggling on any HTML whatsoever. The question was about how to avoid repeated JS in favour of a more elegant, less-lines solution:

Comment: "I am toggling classes on a table to hide specific columns, based on checkboxes that are selected by the user above the table. The checkboxes have IDs "product_1", "product_2" etc."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the ID from the checkboxes and use classes instead. To map the checkboxes to the column you can use the `data` attribute`

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="product" data-column-number="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="product" data-column-number="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="product" data-column-number="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="product" data-column-number="4">
```

```js
const elementCompareTable = document.querySelector('#compare-table');

document.querySelector('.product').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const numberTarget = event.target.dataset.columnNumber;
    elementCompareTable.classList.toggle(`tb-compare-hide-${numberTarget}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the existence of an element before trying to use it.

```
  const compareTable = document.querySelector('#compare-table');
  let arr = [], el;

  const foo = (el, i) => {
    if (el) {
      el.addEventListener("click", () => {
        compareTable.classList.toggle(`tb-compare-hide-${i}`);
      })
      arr.push(el);
    }
  }

  if (compareTable) {
    for (let i=1; i<5; i++) {
      el = document.getElementById(`product_${i}`);
      foo(el, i);
    }
  }

  // you can then use the array indexes to reference the elements
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! I don't need to check if the element exists as it's on a Shopify store and the Liquid templating means that the table must exist for the checkboxes to exist (they are formed from the same product selection). So it's impossible for the user to click the checkbox and the table not be visible. However, probably worth adding anyway!